# mouseListener lost after panel is repainted

Tags: java, swing

My program will allow the user to log in first and if he is logged in,
he will click on labelone first and labeltwo next.
the program will print ("last two cards detected. starting new game..") and allow the user to click on the two labels again.

the problem I am facing is after my panel has been repainted. I cannot click on the labels
anymore.

I know that my codes provided it too lengthy but I have already attempted to tried to cut down my codes from my actual program.

I think the main focus is this block of codes in my controller class.

```
 labelPanel.removeAll();
 Dealer dealer = new Dealer();
 labelPanel.add(new LabelPanel(dealer));
 labelPanel.revalidate();
 labelPanel.repaint();
 new Controller(labelPanel,dealer);
```

I am not sure what happened to my mouselistener. please help

This is are the class. feel free to run it if you guys couldn't understand.

- login as username-> john password -> abc
- click on label one first, after that click on label two. the console will display 
  "last 2 cards detected, starting new game.."
  after that try clicking the labels again(by right it should be clickable but it's not)

LoginPanel.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LoginPanel extends JPanel {

    private JPanel northPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private JPanel southPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
    private JPanel subSouthPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    private JPanel subSouthPanelTwo = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    private GridBagConstraints gbc2 = new GridBagConstraints();
    private JTextField playerUsernameTF = new JTextField(15);
    private JPasswordField playerPasswordTF = new JPasswordField(15);
    private JButton playerLoginBtn = new JButton("Login");

    public LoginPanel() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        gbc2.gridx = 0;
        gbc2.gridy = 0;
        subSouthPanel.add(new JLabel("Username"),gbc2);
        gbc2.gridx = 1;
        gbc2.gridy = 0;
        subSouthPanel.add(playerUsernameTF,gbc2);
        gbc2.gridx = 0;
        gbc2.gridy = 1;
        subSouthPanel.add(new JLabel("Password"),gbc2);
        gbc2.gridx = 1;
        gbc2.gridy = 1;
        subSouthPanel.add(playerPasswordTF,gbc2);
        southPanel.add(subSouthPanel,BorderLayout.CENTER);
        subSouthPanelTwo.add(playerLoginBtn);
        southPanel.add(subSouthPanelTwo,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        add(northPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(southPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH); 
    }


    public JTextField getPlayerUsernameTF() {
        return playerUsernameTF;
    }

    public JPasswordField getPlayerPasswordTF() {
        return playerPasswordTF;
    }

    void addListenerForPlayerLoginBtn(ActionListener actionListener) {
        playerLoginBtn.addActionListener(actionListener);
    }

}
```

LabelPanel.java

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout; 
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class LabelPanel extends JPanel {

    private JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
    private JLabel labelOne;
    private JLabel labelTwo;

    public LabelPanel(Dealer dealer) {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        labelOne = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(dealer.hideCard()));
        labelTwo = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(dealer.hideCard()));
        panel.add(labelOne);
        panel.add(labelTwo);
        add(panel);
    }


    public JLabel getJLabelOne() {
        return labelOne;
    }

    public JLabel getJLabelTwo() {
        return labelTwo;
    }

    void listenerForJLabelOne(MouseListener listenForMouseClick) {
        labelOne.addMouseListener(listenForMouseClick);
    }

    void listenerForJLabelTwo(MouseListener listenForMouseClick) {
        labelTwo.addMouseListener(listenForMouseClick);
    }
}
```

Dealer.java

```
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Dealer {  

    public Dealer() {

    }

    public  Image hideCard() {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/images/blank.png"));  
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        return img;
    }

    public  Image displayFirsCard() {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/images/ClubsAce.png"));   
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

        return img; 
    }

    public  Image displaySecondCard() {
        BufferedImage img = null;
        try {
            img = ImageIO.read(new File("resources/images/ClubsAce.png"));   
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return img;
    }
}
```

Controller.java

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel; 
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class Controller {

    private LabelPanel labelPanel;
    private Dealer dealer;
    private int countdown = 1;
    private Timer timer = new Timer(1000,null);
    private MouseHandler mouseHandler = new MouseHandler();
    private int clicked = 0;

    public Controller(LabelPanel labelPanel,Dealer dealer) {
        clicked = 0;
        this.labelPanel = labelPanel;
        this.dealer = dealer;
        this.labelPanel.listenerForJLabelOne(mouseHandler); 
        this.labelPanel.listenerForJLabelTwo(mouseHandler); 
        this.labelPanel.getJLabelOne().setText("Ace");
        this.labelPanel.getJLabelTwo().setText("Ace");
    }

    private class MouseHandler extends MouseAdapter {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            JLabel label = (JLabel) e.getSource();  
            clicked++;

            if(clicked == 1) {
                labelPanel.getJLabelOne().setIcon((new ImageIcon(dealer.displayFirsCard())));
            }

            if(clicked == 2) {
                labelPanel.getJLabelTwo().setIcon((new ImageIcon(dealer.displaySecondCard())));;
                if(label.getText().equals(label.getText())) {
                    System.out.println("last 2 cards detected, starting new game..");
                    timer = new Timer(1000,new newGameTimer());
                    timer.start();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class newGameTimer implements ActionListener {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(countdown == 0) { 
                timer.stop();
                clicked = 0;
                labelPanel.removeAll();
                Dealer dealer = new Dealer();
                labelPanel.add(new LabelPanel(dealer));
                labelPanel.revalidate();
                labelPanel.repaint();
                new Controller(labelPanel,dealer);
            }
            else {
                countdown--;
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

MainFrame.java

```
import java.awt.CardLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class MainFrame {

    private CardLayout cardLayout = new CardLayout();
    private Dealer dealer = new Dealer();  
    private JPanel cardLayoutPanel = new JPanel();
    private LoginPanel loginPanel = new LoginPanel();
    private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Mouse CLick Test");
    private JPanel dialogPanel = new JPanel();
    private LabelPanel labelPanel = new LabelPanel(dealer);
    public MainFrame() {
        cardLayoutPanel.setLayout(cardLayout);
        cardLayoutPanel.add(loginPanel,"1");
        cardLayout.show(cardLayoutPanel,"1");
        cardLayoutPanel.add(labelPanel,"2");
        frame.add(cardLayoutPanel);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(1024,768);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        loginPanel.addListenerForPlayerLoginBtn(new PlayerLoginBtnActionPerformed());
    }

    public class PlayerLoginBtnActionPerformed implements ActionListener {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            String playerUsername = loginPanel.getPlayerUsernameTF().getText();
            String playerPassword = new String(loginPanel.getPlayerPasswordTF().getPassword());
            if(playerUsername.equals("john") && playerPassword.equals("abc")) { 
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dialogPanel,
                        "Login Successfully!" 
                    ,"Player Login",JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
                cardLayout.show(cardLayoutPanel,"2");
                new Controller(labelPanel,dealer);
            }
            else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dialogPanel,
                        "Wrong Password or Username!" 
                        ,"Error",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
            }   
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[]args) { 
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new MainFrame();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you are adding a `LabelPanel` to a `LabelPanel`

```
labelPanel.add(new LabelPanel(dealer));
```

But you are passing the outer panel to the controller

```
new Controller(labelPanel, dealer);
```

The outer panel no longer actually contains any labels, but only contains the new `LabelPanel`...

A better solution would be to provide the `LabelPanel` with a "reset" option of some kind instead...

Comment: I forgot to mention that my JLabels will be removed after it's matched and shown and after that it will repaint the contents again for the user to click. I not really sure how can I do it. would you mind showing a snippet?

Comment: Instead of creating the labels within th constructor, create some kind of init method, which is called from the constructor. When you remove all the components from LabelPanel, you'll need to call this method again to reinstate the components.